# Javadoc generation in Eclipse generates error

Tags: eclipse, generics, annotations, javadoc

I have a project that compiles well and is running properly. But, when I try to generate the javadoc from eclipse, it returns me following kinds of error:

`(use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)

        ArrayList<CustomerOrder> emp = new ArrayList<CustomerOrder>();`

`(use -source 5 or higher to enable annotations)

    @Override`

What should be done in order to rectify this?

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6 so that is less likely to be the reason... Unless javadoc in particular is using some other version.

Comment: You may have installed 1.6, but it appears Eclipse is still pointing to an older version. Look in Window -> Preferences and double check the build paths. There are also javadoc specific settings...

Comment: @apesa That helped... Changed project specific javadoc settings and it worked :) Thanks a lot.